# How can I make a function return IEnumerable<string> instead of a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following function that returns a string:

```
public static string GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception e)
{
    if (e == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
    }

    var exError = e.Message;
    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
        exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
        if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null)
        {
            exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }

    return exError;
}
```

Can someone help and tell me how I could make this same function return a `IEnumerable<string>` with just one element?

Comment: Why don't you make you function recursive? What if `e.InnerException.InnerException` also has an inner exception?

Comment: @Guillaume: That's probably what got him to a -- *ahem* -- Stack Overflow...

Comment: @Mehrdad Not if you keep checking that `InnerException` is null or not... and you stop calling `GetFormattedErrorMessage` in such a case.

Comment: @Guillaume: lol I was kidding/making a pun :P

Comment: @Mehrdad +1 for the joke

Answer (score 8):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
            }

            var exError = e.Message;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
                if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                {
                    exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
                }
            }

            yield return exError;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Why not just return an array?** It's as simple as `return new string[] { exError };`

I don't understand why people are using a cannon to kill a fly, but you **really** don't need `yield` here...

I should also note:

- **`yield` might not do** what you expect
- `yield` is **slower** (not by much, but it's there)

Answer (score 0):

You should use yield return statement to achieve that.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMessage(Exception e)
{
    yield return e.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `yield return` as others have shown you, but I think it's a bit of an overkill because of what's going on behind the scenes.

Why don't you just create a `List<String>` with one element and return that? It's an `IEnumerable<String>` .

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want only one element in your IEnumerable, but I cannot figure why you want an IEnumerable then.

If you want each message of the exception and its inner exceptions you should do like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetErrorMessages(this Exception e) 
{ 
    if (e == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("e"); 

    yield return e.Message;

    Exception inner = e.InnerException;
    while(inner != null)
    {
        yield return inner.Message; 
        inner = inner.InnerException;
    }
}
```